# Mutual friends query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to create a mutual friends query. But I'm unsure how to merge two tables to get the right result.

So if session user has a friend in common with their friend, mutual friend is one. What I'm looking for is the best solution, fastest and smallest query to do the job.

user table

```
id | first | last | username
----------------------------
```

friends table

```
id | user 1_id | user2_id | status
----------------------------------
```

Attempted query

```
 $collectmutualfriends = mysqli_query($mysqli,"
    SELECT 
               user.id,
               user.first,
               user.last,
               user.username
    FROM       user 
    LEFT JOIN friends as friends1
           ON  friends1.user1_id = user.id
           AND friends1.user2_id = '$user2_id'
           AND friends1.status = 2

    LEFT JOIN friends as friends2
           ON  friends2.user2_id = user.id
           AND friends2.user1_id = '$user2_id'
           AND friends2.status = 2

    GROUP BY friends2.user2_id
    ");
$nummutual = mysqli_num_rows($collectmutualfriends);
if($nummutual==1){
    echo"<a href='mutualfriends.php?username=".$_GET['username']."'>".$nummutual." Mutual Friend<br></a>";
    }else if($nummutual>1){
    echo"<a href='mutualfriends.php?username=".$_GET['username']."'>".$nummutual." Mutual Friends<br></a>";
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
$user1_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$user2_id = $data['id'];
```

$user1_id and $user2_id can be in either user1_id or user2_id on the friends table dependant on who sent the friend request first.

Comment: Can you post some sample data as well?

Comment: When 2 users are friends, you have 1 or 2 rows in table friend?

Comment: What does everyone else do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.*
          FROM friends f1 
    INNER JOIN friends f2 ON (f2.user2_id = f1.user2_id)
    INNER JOIN user u ON (u.id = f2.user2_id)
         WHERE f1.user1_id = '$user1_id'
           AND f2.user1_id = '$user2_id'";
```

Comment: Just like my query its not showing any results on all profiles. 
Session user can be in either user1_id or user2_id row in the friends table dependant on who sent the friend request. Does this make any difference what so ever?

Comment: I see this as a flaw in your design. If user A and user B are friends, the opposite is also true, user B and user A are friends too. In this case you can easily select all friends of user A, or all friends of user B. Doing what you are doing, you will have to query the database twice, looking on column user1_id and again on column user2_id. My advice is to save two rows for each friendship.

Comment: so if in user1_id i have A, and user2_id i have b.. have another row with user1_id as B and user2_id as A, is what you're saying?

Comment: Okay. And what would the query look like with these  joins, unions and or's for other people that may want to use that method! And thank you for your help. Its very much appreciated.